# Choosing an injective resolution of a short exact sequence of complexes

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-functors

> **Lemma:** Given a short exact sequence of cochain complexes in an abelian category $\mathcal{C}$ with enough injectives, $$0 \to
>  P^\bullet \xrightarrow{f} Q^\bullet \xrightarrow{g} R^\bullet \to 0,$$ There
>   exist complexes $I^\bullet, J^\bullet, K^\bullet$ of injective
>   objects, and a diagram commmutative up to homotopy $$ \begin{array}{} 0 & \rightarrow
>  & P^\bullet & \overset{f}{\rightarrow} & Q^\bullet &
>  \overset{g}{\rightarrow} & R^\bullet & \rightarrow & 0 \\ && \!\!\!\!
>  \sim \downarrow a&& \!\!\!\!\sim \downarrow b && \!\!\!\!\sim \downarrow c
>  \\ 0 & \rightarrow & I^\bullet & \overset{u}{\rightarrow} &
>  J^\bullet & \overset{v}{\rightarrow} & K^\bullet & \rightarrow & 0 
>  \end{array} $$ where the rows are exact, and the vertical arrows are
>   homotopy equivalences.

In the [proof](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5dnowJLD2PacGlfVGU2bUhjV1U/view) of this theorem in Iversen's book, he begins by choosing an injective resolution of $Q^\bullet$ and $R^\bullet$, and a map $v$ (unique up to homotopy) between them:
$$ \begin{array}{} 0 & \rightarrow
 & P^\bullet & \overset{f}{\rightarrow} & Q^\bullet &
 \overset{g}{\rightarrow} & R^\bullet & \rightarrow & 0 \\ &&&& \!\!\!\!\sim \downarrow b && \!\!\!\!\sim \downarrow c
 \\  & & & &
 J^\bullet & \overset{v}{\rightarrow} & K^\bullet & \rightarrow & 0 
 \end{array} $$
Since the diagram is homotopy commutative, he selects a homotopy $Q^\bullet \xrightarrow{s} K^\bullet[-1]$ between $c \circ g \Rightarrow v \circ b$.

So far, so good. Then he says

> Choose a map $t:Q^\bullet \xrightarrow{} J^\bullet[-1]$ such that $s=v \circ t$.

This is where I fall off. Why does $s$ necessarily factor through $v[-1]$?

Comment: Do you know the proof of the dual statement?

Comment: Note you are changing the names of your objects and arrows.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Whoops, just fixed it. No, I don't know the proof of the dual. Only for a projective resolution of a short exact sequence of objects (via the "horseshoe lemma"). Not for complexes.

Answer (score 1):

He means choose a map of graded modules, not a chain map. This is possible because $v$ admits a section as a map of graded modules (not as chain complexes).